# Whitney sum formula for topological Pontryagin classes

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Is there a Whitney sum formula for topological rational Pontryagin classes? I thought the answer is yes, but now I cannot find a reference. Is it even true? The PL case would also be of interest.

Comment: Let p(E) denote the total (integral) Pontryagin class of a real bundle E. It's not too hard to show that p(E (+) F) = p(E) * p(F) mod 2-torsion. The 2-torsion term is stated in Theorem 1.6 of Brown's "The Cohomology of BSO_n and BO_n with Integer Coefficients".

Comment: @sdk: Brown's paper is about vector bundles, while my question is about locally trivial bundles with fiber homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry, didn't read carefully enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. A simple argument is that $BO \to BTOP$ is a rational equivalence and an H-space map (in fact even an infinite loop map), so it follows from the Whitney sum formula for vector bundles.

Edit: The argument for this is as follows. Let $\mu : BTOP \times BTOP \to BTOP$ be the map corresponding to Whitney sum of (stable, topological) bundles. The question is whether the identity
$$\mu^* p_n = \sum_{ a + b = n} p_a \otimes p_b$$
holds. As the map $BO \to BTOP$ is a rational equivalence and an H-space map, it is equivalent to verify this equation in the cohomology of $BO$ instead, where it indeed holds.

Comment: Thank you! For my record here is a reference: on p.215 of Boardman-Vogt's book "Homotopy invariant algebraic structures on topological spaces" the authors say (roughtly) that since $O\to Top\to F$ are topological monoid homomorphisms under the Whitney sum, these maps are infinite loop space maps, and hence so are the corresponding maps of classifying spaces $BO\to BTop\to BF$. Actually, instead of this last sequence they write $BO\to Top\to F$ which I assume is a misprint.

Comment: Is it true more generally that for any topological monoid (or at least group) homomorphism $G\to H$  the corresponding map of classifying spaces $BG\to BH$ is an infinite loop map?

Comment: @ConnorMalin: thank you, I see now that Boardman-Vogt's result has quite a few technical assumptions; they speak of symmetrical monoidal functors. I gather, the point is that Whitney sum is commutative.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment in fear that I was missing something. For posterity, I said that usually a group will not be an infinite loop space.

Comment: @Oscar: actually, I am confused. It seems your argument only proves that topological Pontryagin classes satisfy the Whitney sum formula on vector bundles. I need it for topological bundles. Basically, there are two H-maps which are rational equivalences from $BSO$: one to $BSTOP$ and the other one to the product of $K(\mathbb Z, 4i)$ spaces where $i$ varies over positive integers. The latter map is the integral Pontryagin class. One needs to show that  the topological Pontryagin class completes the square rationally. None of the maps from $BSO$ can be reversed, I think.

Comment: @Igor Belegradek: stably and rationally, every topological bundle has a unique vector bundle structure; this is just rephrasing that the map BSO->BSTOP is a rational equivalence. The fact that this map is one of H-spaces says exactly that the induced vector bundle structure is compatible with sums. Note that it suffices to know that BSO->BSTOP is a rational equivalence; you do not need to use that the map to the product of the K(Z,4i)s is one (however, to prove the former, one needs the latter).

Comment: @archipelago and@Oscal: The edit does not address my confusion. I do not understand the claim "rationally, every topological bundle has a unique vector bundle structure". If say $X$ is a finite complex, the cokernel $[X,BO]\to [X,BTOP]$ is finite. The inclusion could be like $2\mathbb Z\subset\mathbb Z$. If $x\in [X,BTOP]$, which vector bundle is $x$ equivalent to rationally? If $t\in [X, BTOP]$ has order $n$, i.e. $nt=0$, how to we know that $p(t)=1$? Why is $p(x+t)=p(x)p(t)$? Here $p=1+p_1+p_2+\dots$, the total Pontryagin class.

Comment: If $K_Q$ is the product of $K(4i,\mathbb Q)$ spaces over all integers $i>0$, then all we have is an isomorphism $[BTOP, K_Q]\to [BO, K_Q]$ which sends the topological Pontryagin class to the usual one.

Comment: $[X,BSO_\mathbb{Q}]\rightarrow [X,BSTOP_\mathbb{Q}]$ is an isomorphism. The rational Pontryagin classes of $x\in [X,BSTOP]$ only depend on its image in $[X,BSTOP_\mathbb{Q}]$.